# SQL Server trigger to Log columns updated from a stored procedure dynamically

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, triggers

I have a stored procedure which will update ~100 columns in a single table when it is executed.

I want to create a trigger on the impacted table that will:

1. Identify all (actually) updated values
   (So if the new value is '1' and the old value is '1', then ignore it)
2. From the list of actually changed values, get the column name and data value
3. Take the column name and old data value and store them into a log table via an insert
   (INSERT ColumnName, Value INTO LogTable)

I have a solution that will work, but I would have to create a temp table and insert a row into the temp table for each column that I know is impacted... something like having 100 of these:

```
INSERT INTO @TempTable (
ID,
ColumnName,
OldColumnValue
)
SELECT i.ID, 'Column1', i.Column1
FROM inserted i 
INNER JOIN deleted d ON d.ID = i.ID
WHERE COALESCE(d.Column1, '') != COALESCE(i.Column1, '')
```

After doing that insert for column1 all the way to column100, I would just insert all the records from the @TempTable into the log table .

There has to be a more dynamic approach to solve this, but I can't think of it.

*For the sake of simplicity, lets assume that the values will always be [TEXT] as will the value in the LogTable.

Comment: *"There has to be a more dynamic approach to solve this, but I can't think of it."* Yes, with dynamic SQL. But regardless of if you use a dynamic approach or not you'd need to `CONVERT` all of your columns to the same data in your unpivot, and that could result is data loss/changes. I personally feel that storing a history of the rows is a far better process.

Comment: @Larnu Agreed, although unfortunately that is not a possible solution.

Comment: *"although unfortunately that is not a possible solution."* why not?

Comment: ALso *"lets assume that the values will always be [TEXT]"* Why are you using `text`? It's been deprecated since 2005. You should have switched to `varchar(MAX)` long ago.

Comment: @Larnu Is that a rhetorical question? Simply because it is a requirement that only changed data is kept in the log. Imagine that this stored procedure was executed thousands of times a day and most of the time the values do not change? What good is the log then?

Comment: @Larnu "Why are you using text? It's been deprecated since 2005." I'll go ask the original developer?

Comment: *"I'll go ask the original developer?"* No good asking them, if they've left the company; you should be speaking to the current one(s).

Comment: In step 3 you plan to use `INSERT ColumnName, Value INTO LogTable`, but your temporary table includes `ID`. Why? You don't want to log _which_ row was updated. Do you consider `null` and empty strings as equivalent? `COALESCE(d.Column1, '') != COALESCE(i.Column1, '')` does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without the definition of your table, I can't answer this in full, however, what you need to do here is unpivot all your data, and then when the value doesn't equal the other, insert it into your log table. This means that your query will need to look something like this:

```sql
INSERT INTO dbo.LogTable (ID,
                          ColumnName,
                          OldColumnValue)
SELECT d.ID,
       V.ColumnName,
       V.OldColumnValue
FROM deleted d
     JOIN inserted i ON d.ID = i.ID
     CROSS APPLY (VALUES(N'Column1',i.Column1, d.Column1),
                        (N'Column2',i.Column2, d.Column2),
                        (N'Column3',i.Column3, d.Column3),
                        (N'Column4',i.Column4, d.Column4))V(ColumnName, NewColumnValue, OldColumnValue)
WHERE V.NewColumnValue != V.OldColumnValue
   OR (V.NewColumnValue IS NULL AND V.OldColumnValue IS NOT NULL)
   OR (V.NewColumnValue IS NOT NULL AND V.OldColumnValue IS NULL);
```

Note, however, that a column must be made up of the same data type, and I doubt all of your columns *are* the same data type. As such you are going to need to explicitly `CONVERT` all of your columns to an `(n)varchar`. For columns that are a date and time value, I would strongly suggest you use a style code in the explicit `CONVERT` too; like `112` for `date`, and perhaps `126` for other date and time data types.